# Search For Text And Select Used Range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am needing to search Row 1 and find the text `Full Name` then find the used range in that column and copy it.  I have tried this syntax:

```
Sub Macro1()
  Dim Found As Range, LastRow As Long

  Sheets(1).Activate
  Set Found = Rows(1).Find(what:="Full Name", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Found Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Found.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

However, that selects the data in the active cell.  For example, if cell A1 is selected it only copies the data from cell A1.  What must I change in order for the used range of the row with the text `Full Name` to be copied?

--Yes the text `Full Name` exists on the worksheet on `Sheet(1)`

Comment: You are telling to copy only what is selected, change `Selection.Copy` to `Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(1).Cells(1,Found.Column),Sheets(1).Cells(LastRow,Found.Column)).Copy`

Comment: you're copying selection but not selecting the last row. Are you wanting to copy the contents of the usedrange or copy the usedrange address as a value?

Comment: @Zerk - I am wanting to find the text Full Name, and copy from cell (example) B2: LastRow

Comment: @ScottCraner - that got it thank you

Comment: @ScottCraner - if you post as answer I will accept since that solved my issue.